# capistrano regenerating wrappers error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler, capistrano3

I'm trying to deploy a rails project via capistrano v 3.1.0 and rubygems-bundler gem.

I've executed  following commands on local machine and on server i'm trying to deploy to via ssh.

> gem install rubygems-bundler
>   gem regenerate_binstubs

But when i try to run capistrano deploy task it's interrupted  with the following message and all later input does nothing

> DEBUG[304abaa0]   Regenerating ruby-2.1.3 wrappers DEBUG[304abaa0]
>     ........ DEBUG[304abaa0]    The bundler binstubs directory is in the
>   current directory, which may be unsafe. DEBUG[304abaa0]   Consider
>   using rubygems-bundler instead =>
>   https://github.com/mpapis/rubygems-bundler DEBUG[304abaa0]    Remove the
>   BUNDLE_BIN line from .bundle/config to disable this prompt.
>   DEBUG[304abaa0]   Are you sure you want to add the bundler binstubs
>   directory to the path? DEBUG[304abaa0]    (anything other than 'Yes'
>   will cancel) >

Can you give me any advice? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgraded rake to v 10.4, added line `set :bundle_flags, '--no-binstubs'` to deploy.rb
This fixed the problem!

Answer (score 2):

Answer is already accepted but still I want to post solution that I have applied which might helpful to other.

I was facing same kind of issue,  I resolved it by removing hooks from `~/.rvm/hooks` directory. Please check more comments in github issue posted over here : https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/2725#issuecomment-156648585

Hope this might be help to somebody !!